# only build script and other plugins script blocks are allowed before plugins

Tags: gradle, plugins

I want to use gradle plugin having this syntax

```
 plugins {
  id "id" version "version"
}
```

but i have the error of

```
only build script and other plugins script blocks are allowed before plugins
```

I moved it to the bloc buildscript but still not working.

How can i apply this kind of plugin ?

This is the plugin that I want to include in my project

[gradle git properties plugin](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties)

and here is the output of my gradle version

```
    Gradle 4.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-11-08 08:59:45 UTC
Revision:     e4f4804807ef7c2829da51877861ff06e07e006d

Groovy:       2.4.12
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Whenever you write a `build.gradle` script and use the new `plugins` script block, you need to put it as first block in the file. The only exceptions from this rule are other `plugins` blocks or the special `buildScript` block, which always must go first.

As an example, this script is fine:

```
plugins {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```

This one is also fine:

```
buildScript {
    // ...
}

plugins {
    // ...
}

repositories {
    // ...
}
```

But this one is invalid:

```
repositories {
     // ...
}

plugins {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How first scenario one even possible?! In root `build.gradle`, `dependencies {` is inside of `buildscript {`, and you're saying to solve the error, we should set the `plugins { after `buildScript {` and before `dependencies {`

Comment: The `dependencies` block inside a `buildscript` block is not the same as the regular `dependencies` block.  Furthermore, this is completely independent from whether the project is a root project or not.

Comment: Nailed it on the head ye did! Great suggestion!

Comment: buildScript {
    // ...
}

plugins {
    // ...
}

repositories {
    // ...
} Worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed a plugin line before the android block that said apply plugin: 'com.android.application'. Since the firebase configuration ask me for the 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin I just add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3):

Google firebase documentation is kind of messed up, they are asking to add the following code

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

but it should really be following at the very top of the file (more like include)

```
apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Make sure this is the first line in the file.

Answer (score -6):

I solved this just by deleting.

task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }

Comment: It is not working saying tasl clean already exist