# Gradle - Syntax error using plugin method with closure as argument

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Below are two tasks `hello` & `printProperties` in `build.gradle`:

```
task('hello', {
            description("Hey student! Run this one :D")
            group("Our demo")
            doLast({println("Hello World!")})
            }
     )

plugins({
    id('java')
})

ext({
    springVersion = "3.1.0.RELEASE"
    emailNotification = "build@master.org"
})

sourceSets.all({ ext.purpose = null })

sourceSets({
    main({
        purpose = "production"
    })
    test({
        purpose = "test"
    })
    plugin({
        purpose = "production"
    })
})

task('printProperties', {
    doLast({
        println(springVersion)
        println(emailNotification)
        sourceSets.matching({ it.purpose == "production" }.each({ println it.name }))
    })
})
```

---

that gives error:

```
> startup failed:
  build file '/../../build.gradle': 8:
only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
```

---

Why `plugins({id('java')})` give groovy scripted syntax error?

Comment: Define the task after the plugins block?

Comment: @tim_yates why developers use declarative syntax? it is not readable...I could not understand single line of groovy code with declarative syntax. Really painful.   Ya got resolved the above error.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying 

Comment: I think what he is saying is that he finds the gradle dsl with parens and commas removed hard to read (vs the question where they are included). IMHO this is a function of how much time you have spent with a DSL. When you first start out you want all your commas and parens. Once you've lived with it for a few years, the less non-essential, not-contributing-to-the-information-content chars I have to parse mentally, the better. 

I'm also a clojure programmer. In clojure, everybody  starts out hating the parens. Five years later I have not heard a single person dislike them. Just my 2c.

Comment: @MatiasBjarland Spending time with DSL is same as to go far from regular programming languages (C/Python/java/GoLang/TyoeScript) that follow another kind of syntax that looks a bit close to scripted syntax of groovy.

Answer (score 1):

It's answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611069/1250435

> Whenever you write a build.gradle script and use the new plugins
>   script block, you need to put it as first block in the file. The only
>   exceptions from this rule are other plugins blocks or the special
>   buildScript block, which always must go first.