# How to translate DSL syntax to scripted syntax

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, dsl

Below is the code snippet in groovy DSL:

```
plugins {
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.2.0"
}
```

---

that is difficult for me to understand, if below is the corresponding scripted syntax:

```
plugins({
  id(
      {
        "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow", 
        version("5.2.0")
      }
   )
})
```

---

How to translate a DSL syntax to scripted syntax? Because scripted syntax is more readable syntax for me.

Comment: What do you mean with "scripted syntax" do you mean kotlin script instead of groovy script?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings this query has scripted syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59507030/3317808

Comment: So you just add the redundant parentheses back in and call it scripted syntax?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings yes.. exactly, but am confused how to convert plugin syntax written in DSL(given in the above query, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id(String)` method in the [plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependenciesSpec.html) block returns a [PluginDependencySpecImpl](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugin-use/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/management/internal/DefaultPluginManagementSpec.java) which has the methods `version(String)` and `apply(boolean)`. So you just need to write it like so:

```
plugins ({
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow").version("5.2.0")
})
```

The pattern at work is called [Command Chain](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html).

> Groovy lets you omit parentheses around the arguments of a method call
>   for top-level statements. "command chain" feature extends this by
>   allowing us to chain such parentheses-free method calls, requiring
>   neither parentheses around arguments, nor dots between the chained
>   calls. The general idea is that a call like a b c d will actually be
>   equivalent to a(b).c(d). This also works with multiple arguments,
>   closure arguments, and even named arguments.

MrHaki has a nice explanation why this works [here](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/05/groovy-goodness-command-chain.html).

Comment: How do you know that there is dot between `id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow")` and `version("5.2.0")`? this is the problem for me

Comment: Read the explanation I linked from MrHaki and take a look at the links I added and then you'll see.

Comment: How would I convert the complete script?

Comment: You'll have to go over every block and see how it is defined, but honestly I don't recommend it, just use the official syntax like it is documented, otherwise you are just making it difficult for everyone else and you can't use examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) **is** the preferred approach of applying plugins.

The [legacy plugins application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application) (scripted syntax) equivalent is:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
```

That is **a lot** more to write than the plugins DSL.

The Gradle team has documented this as *legacy*. So whether you like the new `plugins { }` syntax or not, the legacy method will eventually go away.

Comment: I did not understand your answer. above code is scripted syntax?

Comment: Gradle has many newer ways of applying configurations. Generally, the older way to configures things is generally known as "scripted" syntax.

Comment: ok...am trying to write gradle syntax like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60750513/3317808