# Build Failing: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, groovy

I recently added Kotlin to my Java project, my build started failing, and I am getting this message:

"only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed" and this "Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:"

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have my jdk set as 1.8 (as you see below), so the existing answer to this question does not seem to apply.

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility '1.8'
        targetCompatibility '1.8'
    }
```

As for the brackets, here's my project build.gradle file where it's referencing.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.5'

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.70'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm at the bleary eyed stage of the day. I moved it before allprojects and it worked. This was helpful: 
[only build script and other plugins script blocks are allowed before plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610901/only-build-script-and-other-plugins-script-blocks-are-allowed-before-plugins)